# How to make method of a base class use inherited protected members that derived class sets? C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, protected

I've got a problem that even though the code in the loop has the correct pointer type ( as call to `tells()` shows ) it still uses `getPointer()` over default constructed `Triangle` class, if I'm not wrong.
How to make a call to `getPointer()` in loop return a pointer to the memory where the coordinates saved?

main.cpp:

```
#include <triangles.h>
#include <memory>
#include<QVector>
class C {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Triangle> shp;
};

int main() {
    QVector<C> vc;
    C t, a, b;
    t.shp = std::make_shared<Triangle>(10,20,30,40,50,60);
    a.shp = std::make_shared<EqualTriangle>(10,20, 53);
    b.shp = std::make_shared<IsoscelesTriangle>(10,20, 53, 152);
    vc.push_back(t);
    vc.push_back(a);
    vc.push_back(b);
    for(auto x: vc) {
        const QPointF * p = x.shp->getPointer();
        x.shp->tell();
        qDebug() << (void*) p;
        qDebug() << p[0]<< p[1]<<p[2];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

triangles.h:

```
#define TRIANGES_H
#include<QPointF>
#include<cmath>
#include<QDebug>
class Triangle
{
public:
    Triangle() = default;
    Triangle(float ax, float ay, float bx, float by, float cx, float cy);
    Triangle(QPointF a, QPointF b, QPointF c);
    const QPointF *getPointer() {qDebug() << "triangle getpoint called"; return points; }
    virtual void tell() { qDebug()<<"triangle tells";}

protected:
    QPointF points[3];
};

class IsoscelesTriangle : public Triangle
{
public:
    IsoscelesTriangle() = default;
    IsoscelesTriangle(QPointF point, uint side_len, uint base_len);
    IsoscelesTriangle(float px, float py, uint side_len, uint base_len ): Triangle() {
        IsoscelesTriangle(QPointF(px, py), side_len, base_len);
    virtual void tell() { qDebug()<<"iso triangle tells";}

};

class EqualTriangle : public IsoscelesTriangle
{
public:
    EqualTriangle() = default;
    EqualTriangle(QPointF point, uint side_len ):IsoscelesTriangle() { IsoscelesTriangle(point, side_len, side_len);}
    EqualTriangle(float px, float py, uint side_len) :IsoscelesTriangle() {
        EqualTriangle(QPointF(px,py), side_len);
    }
    virtual void tell() { qDebug()<<"equal triangle tells";}

};

#endif // TRIANGES_H
```

triangles.cpp:

```
#include "triangles.h"
#include <QDebug>

Triangle::Triangle(float ax, float ay, float bx, float by, float cx, float cy)
{
    points[0] = QPointF(ax, ay);
    points[1] = QPointF(bx, by);
    points[2] = QPointF(cx, cy);
}

Triangle::Triangle(QPointF a, QPointF b, QPointF c)
{
    points[0] = a;
    points[1] = b;
    points[2] = c;
}

IsoscelesTriangle::IsoscelesTriangle(QPointF point, uint side_len, uint base_len) : Triangle()
{
    points[0] = point;
    points[1] = QPointF(point.x()+base_len, point.y());
    points[2] = QPointF(point.x()+base_len/2, point.y() +sqrt(side_len*side_len - (base_len*base_len)/4));
}
```

Output:

```
triangle getpoint called
triangle tells
0x560340e8fd38
QPointF(10,20) QPointF(30,40) QPointF(50,60)
triangle getpoint called
equal triangle tells
0x560340e8fd88
QPointF(0,0) QPointF(0,0) QPointF(0,0)
triangle getpoint called
iso triangle tells
0x560340e8fdd8
QPointF(0,0) QPointF(0,0) QPointF(0,0)
```

Comment: What would be an example of "expected" output here?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker I hoped to return computed points of constructed equal and isosceles triangles. Instead I get zeroed QPointFs

Comment: rather than putting the answer to your post into the posted question itself, please move that material to an actual answer that you post. That way your question will show that it has an answer when people are doing a search for a similar problem. You can post your answer and then a day or two later you will be able to select it as the accepted answer. Doing this also gives you the opportunity to gain rep from from the question and the answer should people do upvotes.

Comment: @RichardChambers thank you for a helpful advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in this code is that when constructors of derived classes (all but the unused here `IsoscelesTriangle(QPointF ,uint, uint)` are called they invoke additional constructors inside themselves thus creating a temporary object instead of initializing class fields.

Also it would be a good idea to make `points` a private member of a base class and create a protected member function `void setPoints(QPointF a, QPointF b, QPointF c)` in base class for encapsulation's sake.

Fixed constructors would look like that:

triangles.cpp

```
IsoscelesTriangle::IsoscelesTriangle(QPointF point, uint side_len, uint base_len)
{
    QPointF a = point;
    QPointF b = QPointF(point.x()+base_len, point.y());
    QPointF c = QPointF(point.x()+base_len/2, point.y() +sqrt(side_len*side_len - (base_len*base_len)/4));
    setPoints(a,b,c);
}
```

triangles.h

```
    IsoscelesTriangle(float a, float b, uint side_len, uint base_len):IsoscelesTriangle(QPointF(a,b), side_len, base_len) {}
    EqualTriangle(QPointF point, uint side_len ): IsoscelesTriangle(point, side_len, side_len) { }
    EqualTriangle(float x, float y, uint side_len ): IsoscelesTriangle(QPointF(x,y), side_len, side_len) { }
```